# Pairing several jQueryUI sortables without crossover

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm working on a drag-drop-reorder widget of sorts, where a user can drag elements from one sortable (let's call it the LEFT box) to another (RIGHT box)

The problem here is, I'll be having multiple such widgets.

What I want to do is to PAIR them, so that the item from LEFT box of one widget cannot be dragged to another widget's RIGHT box.

My current pseudocode is:

```
<ul class = "left">
...
</ul>

<ul class = "right">
...
</ul>


$('.left').sortable
  connectWith: '.right'
```

As the two UL's are siblings, I've tried stuff like

```
$('.left').sortable
  connectWith: '+ .right'
```

This doesn't work, as sortable's internal code does not consider the current element while trying to locate the connected element.

I've also tried using the `containment` option to point to the parent of both ULs, but that doesn't work, either.

What would you suggest I do?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

In the onReceive callback of all sortables, I called this method:

```
checkPairing = (event, ui, el) ->
  firstParent = $(el).parent().get(0)
  secondParent = $(ui.sender).parent().get(0)
  $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel') unless firstParent == secondParent
```

Whenever a receive event occurs for any sortable, get the parent elements of both sortables (the DOM, not the jQuery object) and compare them. If they indeed are a pair, they'd be equal. If not, cancel the event.

It took me time to figure out (1) you can't compare two jQuery objects by just an equality operator and (2) a `return false` won't help, you've got to call the cancel method.

The pairing works as expected.